# What is the Authorize Endpoint when the web app and the apis server are deployed seperatly?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4, aspnetboilerplate

In ASP.NEt Zero, I am trying to integrate with Zapier using Identity Server 4. I managed to run it, however, what will authorize endpoint would be?

I am using .Net core with angular version where the login is happening in another web server. However, OAuth2 needs an authorization endpoint where the user authenticate, authoirze the app, and return a token.

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed you're trying to get the endpoint on the server-side. To get any endpoint for your IDP, you need to read your IDP's discovery document, located at `http://youridpurl.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`. You can do this with the help of [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2) as follows:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://youridpurl.com");
var authorizeEndpoint = disco.AuthorizeEndpoint;
```

See the [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/discovery.html) and [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2) documentation for a more information.

Comment: Thanks. for the answer! I am using a framwork called asp.net boilerplate, which has a seperated front-end and backend projects. The url you've mentioned is correct, however, it does not work scince the authorization page should be in the front-end (angular) app. Am I right?

Comment: @Homam No problem. Have you taken a look at the [Javascript OAuth2 sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Clients/src/JsOAuth2/wwwroot/index.html)? It looks like the idea is similar, except you  hardcode the authorise endpoint that's in your discovery document, rather than using IdentityModel on the server-side to read it.